# How common are single-author research articles in cognitive psychology?

Tags: cognitive-psychology

Are single-author research articles looked down upon?

Comment: The question might be more suitable on academia.SE, but I'm far from certain it won't be closed and/or downvoted there as well.

Comment: I think as the question is posed, the post is more suitable here than Academia, as single-author papers are much more prevalent in some disciplines like Anthropology than in the STEM sciences for example. In other words, this question is discipline-dependent.

Comment: It's a better fit for academia

Answer (score 1):

To target the question in the question body here:

This question is quite opinion-based, because everyone can decide to frown upon something. However, I think that, in general, it's much more about:

- **Who the author** is, *i.e.*, what is their track record in the field;
- What their **affiliation** is;
- What the **quality of the article** is;
- What the **quality** (*e.g.* impact factor) **of the journal** is.

These considerations are, at least to me, much more important than how many authors follow or precede someone in the author list. I would never judge an article on the number of authors *per se*. Lastly, (invited) review papers are often authored by just one author, even in the STEM sciences.